# Hide Icons of the button when the screen resolution changes or is resized

Tags: html, css, reactjs, angular, bootstrap-4

Please refer my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/pwdyj1ea/1/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
         <span> Icon</span>
         <span>Primary</span>
       </button>
      <!--few more buttons-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

So basically i have a row with two columns which have buttons(with fa icons) and text box inside it.
I want to hide the icon when the first column goes to second line. Basically what i want to achieve is no matter how much i resize the window the buttons should always remain in the same line and not fall to the next line for the first col - col-md-8.

I tried using media queries but it functions according to my screen size so when i zoom in my screen size is the same so the icons are still there instead of disappearing.

Comment: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Comment: But this again has to do with the screen size. I want to hide the icons when the div col goes to next line for eg when i zoom my screen

Comment: For zoom i think you have to intercept it with javascript

Comment: but how will i come to know that the col-md-8 is occupying two lines. Is there a way to reduce the spacing between the buttons or squeeze them when the screen size changes.